# App publishing(Windows Store)

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10

I recently created the first 2 apps of my life and triggered the publication process. I noticed that Microsoft services certifies apps within a day or two now it has been almost 4 days and there is no news of the certification passing or failing. Please tell me how i can get my app certified faster.

Comment: I've had apps pass in hours or a few days - the latter is usually as it's been selected for hardware testing which takes a little longer sometimes, but you can check the status in the Dev Center and check what stage in the process it is - you won't get an email for example if it fails

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft says it usually takes 16 Hours for Certification. But that is totally not the case. One of my app's Last certification took 2 days (This app had FB, Twitter and Youtube Integration). i updated another app before that with minimum functionality and it took less than 10 Hrs.( this was a very simple app helpful for developers )

[Here is the URL that describes Certification process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/the-app-certification-process)

Comment: Actually the official page says that after certification and publishing an app takes almost 16 hours to get to store(be noticed by other users).

Comment: My app seems to be hanging for more than five days but there is no information yet i contacted support and they told that it might have taken some time as it is my first app.